# Baseband and radio in Android

Tags: hardware, kernel

In the below picture

1, It seems that the radio firmware don't need a linux driver in Android, It just need a user space shared library, is it?

2, what is baseband?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From the picture it would appear you are correct.  Note #2, however.
2. The baseband is the modem firmware.